# Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, compiling

Although my file compiles fine, I get the following message:

> Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table... Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary Error: Couldn't read xref table

I have seen some other posts - like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/tikz-externalize-doesnt-work-missing-trailer-directory-and-xref-table) - but so far as I know, I am not externalising Tikz figures (although I do have them; added tag just in case).

Why do I get this error? I cannot pin down which section of my (huge) document or packages produces this. Hence, showing a MWE seems not possible. :(

Comment: Maybe the run producing the pdf did not complete successfully and did not finish the pdf file. Does the log file contain any errors?

Comment: Here is the log file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23230695/ I don't know what to look for.

Comment: My comment on that question applies equally here. Also, what gives this error? In that case, the error is produced by the compiler. But you say your file compiles fine. Is this something your PDF viewer complains about?

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded *late* - with a few notable exceptions, it should be loaded *last*.

Comment: I think it should be possible to narrow down the problem by successively commenting out parts of the source code. Based on the log file alone it is difficult/impossible to locate the problem.

Comment: The document of your log file has only 11 pages, that's not huge.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually, I was already trying to pin down the problem by commenting and uncommenting sections, but gave up. I showed the log of the last attempt. Should have showed the original one. Anyway, will try again.

Comment: I solved the issue by deleting all output files. There might have been a problem in one of them, which was transmitted across compilations. No idea why this could be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by deleting all output files.